# Sample "Hello-world" app in Android takes 18MB of memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ram, android-memory

I created a new Android project using eclipse, which is a "Hello World!" application.

I ran this app on my `Nexus 4 with Kitkat 4.4.4` and checked the memory usage using the command :

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.example.test`

which gave me the following results

[image: Memory Dump]

As per my understanding of this, the application is taking around **18MB** of RAM.

This is what is bothering me that how a simple application like this can take so much of memory.

Is this a normal behaviour in Android application? or I am doing something wrong.

please help me figure out this.

For reference my source code for the `MainActivity`

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

and the 'activity_main.xml' in `reference` folder

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

I ran the same application on Android version `4.3 Jellybean` and command

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.example.test`

gave me this result:

[image: memory used in 4.3 Jellibean]

Is this difference because of different version only? Why Google has changed this behaviour in Kitkat as compared to JellyBean

Comment: I think 18MB of RAM is not much...

Comment: @BlazeTama, compared to what the application is doing I thought 18MB is too much

Comment: try removing padding attributes or use "dp" instead of "@dimen/xyz".  the memory is used in converting xml into a java object for inflating it.

Comment: Why u have taken 
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"

Comment: There are no need of this code..

Comment: I removed the code ` android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"`<br> After this only 400KB was removed. not much of a difference !!!

Comment: @Mayank But "what the application is doing" includes all of the framework necessary to launch, manage, and display an Android application. Graphics libraries, event handlers, and so on.

Comment: i think @chrylis is right, you notice that cuz your app is simple, ex, try to compress (winrar) a text file contains 3 letters, it's size will be 3 bytes, and after compress the archive file will be something like 60 bytes, so compressing made the file larger!

Comment: Ah the joys of memory profiling :). You have to consider there's a cost for Dalvik (Android's JVM), a cost for its JIT compiler, a cost for loading your resources and all the default android resources (logo, event hooks, etc.), a cost for rendering the UI and many, many other things. Your hello world app is not really a natively compiled command line hello world app that should virtually take no memory. It's a UI app running on a virtual machine. This means it'll consume more resources (and will inevitably be slower) but gives you various advantages as a result.